# SAS conditional logic to execute another sas program based on condition

Tags: if-statement, sas, sas-macro, proc-sql

I have a dataset naming `error_table` as follows. All the variables are character

```
Errorno   Error     Resolution  
001     login       check 
002     datacheck   check
```

I wanted a logic that executes a `sas` program If the `Errorno` is not in `001` and `002`. Else stop execution and display the `error_table`.

I tried the following

```
%macro test();
   proc sql;
      select trim(Error_No) into: num from error_table;
   quit;

   %if &num. not in ("001","002") %then %do;
       %include "/path/dev/program.sas";
   %end;
   %else %do;
      proc print data = error_table;
      run;
   %end;
%mend;
%test;
```

But, it is throwing an error.

Can anyone please correct the logic.

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: Curious about your logic. Do you mean: if there is any record in error_table where errorno Not in ("001" "002") then run the program; else print error_table?

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch out for the case when the `SELECT` returns zero rows.  You should set a default value to the macro variable NUM.

Is your dataset variable numeric or character? Use the `TRIMMED` or `SEPARATED BY` clause instead of the `TRIM()` function to prevent spaces in the macro variable that is generated by the `INTO` clause.

```
%let num=NONE;
select Error_No into: num trimmed from error_table;
```

Remember that to the macro processor everything is a string so don't but quotes around the values you are trying to match unless they are actually part of the value.

```
%if NOT (&num. in (001,002)) %then %do;
```

Also to use the `IN` operator in macro code you need to make sure you have set the `MINDELIMITER` option.

Comment: I think you meant `MINOPERATOR`. Also `in` operator doesn't require `(`, `)` and `,`.

Answer (score 0):

I would sugest moving condition with error codes to `proc sql`.

```
proc sql;
   select count(*) into :num_errors
   from error_table
   where Errorno in ("001", "002");
quit;
```

Then in macrovariable you have number of errors that are `001` or `002`.
Next step is to check macro-condition:

```
%if &num_errors. > 0 %then %do;
   %include "/path/dev/program.sas";
%end;
%else %do;
   proc print data = error_table;
   run;
%end;
%mend;
```